# Get Json Object From QueryString c#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, query-string

**The best I found was that available solutions at stack do not have answer for nested json object**, they only address liner json values. But I have data to send is like

```
 { ob: { a: "78", b: { a: "gffg", h: {m:67, j:"fff"} } } }
```

If I want to do it in php i would just do

```
$json = $_POST['ob'];
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

**But In c# I can'not do that**. So I would appreciate any built-in method if available and I would love to be helped to **fix my following code**

I want to make a nested dictionary (I would prefer JOBject though). For ease of showing output I have serialized the result,

What result I have achieved yet from following code is
`{"a":"78","ob":{},"ob.b":{"a":"gffg"},"ob.b.h":{"m":"67","j":"fff"}}` but desired result is like sent data  `{ "ob": { "a": "78", "b": { "a": "gffg", "h": {m:67, "j":"fff"} } } }` Code is

```
    string getJsonStringFromQueryString()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var nvc = Request.QueryString;
        foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
        {
            string[] values = nvc.GetValues(key);
            string tempKey = key;
            tempKey = tempKey.Replace("[", ".").Replace("]", "");
            if (values.Length == 1)
                dic.Add(tempKey, values[0]);
            else
                dic.Add(tempKey, values);
        }

        //It is giving me
        {[ob.a, 78]}
        {[ob.b.a, gffg]}
        {[ob.b.h.m, 67]}
        {[ob.b.h.j, fff]}

        var result = makeNestedObject(dic);
        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);    

        return json;
    }
```

I am trying to add the leaf keys and their values as it is and all other keys as dictionary

```
    Dictionary<string, object> makeNestedObject(Dictionary<string, object> qsDictionar)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (string key in qsDictionar.Keys)
        {
            string temp = "";
            if (key.Contains("."))
            {
                string[] ar = key.Split('.');
                if (ar.Length > 2)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ar.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        temp = ar[0];
                        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                        {
                            temp += "." + ar[j];
                        }
            //above is getting the previous key i want to use as dictionary, leaving the leaf key.
                        try
                        {
                            Dictionary<string, object> forTry = (Dictionary<string, object>)result[temp];
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            result.Add(temp, new Dictionary<string, object>());
                        }
                    }
                    ((Dictionary<string, object>)result[temp]).Add(ar[ar.Length - 1], qsDictionar[key]);
                }
                else
                    result.Add(ar[1], qsDictionar[key]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I myself am using `JObject` from `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;` to turn strings into JSON objects. Through `JObject.Parse(json)`, you can access keys through using ['key_name'] on the JObject

Comment: Yes, dear we can. But problem is in makinh JObject from querystring

Answer (score 4):

Following method gives you complete solution for any json object.

```
    string getJsonStringFromQueryString()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var nvc = Request.QueryString;
        foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
        {
            string[] values = nvc.GetValues(key);
            string tempKey = key;
            tempKey = tempKey.Replace("[", ".").Replace("]", "");
            if (values.Length == 1)
                dic.Add(tempKey, values[0]);
            else
                dic.Add(tempKey, values);
        }

        string vald = Request.QueryString["ob"];

        var result = makeNestedObject(dic);
        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
        return json;
    }

    Dictionary<string, object> makeNestedObject(Dictionary<string, object> qsDictionar)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (string key in qsDictionar.Keys)
        {
            if (key.Contains("."))
            {
                List<string> keysList = key.Split('.').ToList();
                Dictionary<string, object> lastAddedDictionary = result;
                while (keysList.Count > 1)
                {
                    if (!lastAddedDictionary.ContainsKey(keysList[0]))
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, object> temp = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        lastAddedDictionary[keysList[0]] = temp;
                        lastAddedDictionary = temp;
                    }
                    else                        
                        lastAddedDictionary = (Dictionary<string, object>)lastAddedDictionary[keysList[0]];                        
                    keysList.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                lastAddedDictionary[keysList[0]] = qsDictionar[key];
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(key, qsDictionar[key]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Quite late, but thanks for your answer! Only add 'keysList.RemoveAll(y => String.IsNullOrEmpty(y));' once you created the keysList to ensure you correctly handle Array only values.